# Optimizing the execution plan of SQL Server query with subquery in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause, sql-execution-plan

There are two tables one with the actual fact data(table1) and the other table(table2) with more like a tracker information on date.
I am trying to get all the fact data from table1 where the date field is less than max(date) from table 2.
Following is the query I am using

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE date < SELECT MAX(date) from TABLE2`

When I check the execution plan, I see SQL server is trying to optimize the query by using an inner join instead of straightforward filter condition

[image: Subquery in where condition]

When I replace the same subquery with a value, the execution plan shows a straightforward filter

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE date < '2023-03-01'`

[image: value in where conditon]

My understanding is that an inner join is a costly operation when compared with a filter. How can I optimize the where condition with a subquery to avoid inner join and run it before the main query and provide it as a value in the final where condition

Comment: Are the two queries comparable? They're filtering `TABLE1` in opposite directions so are likely entirely different sets of rows.

Comment: It's true, the queries are different so that's the first thing to check. Anyway, as I understand it, using a static value (i.e. `2023-03-01`) allows the query planner to work smarter, as opposed to using an unknown / runtime value `SELECT MAX(date) from TABLE2` _an inner join is a costly operation when compared with a filter_ That sounds right but I'm not sure if it's true. It's actually a very strange choice given that it doesn't actually have a _list_ of dates to join to, it only has one. Are you absolutely certain the queries are functionally the same?

Comment: Apologies guys. It's a mistake I had different operators. I have corrected it now. Both functionally are returning the same output. It's just that I want to filter the data based on the value that table2 returns. Stored procedure is an option where I can store that in a variable, but for business reasons I cannot have that in a stored procedure as these queries are built on the fly when an API endpoint is called and the logic is common for multiple tables and implementing a stored procedure for one table can become a huge investment.

Comment: Please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show tables and index definitions

Comment: This showplan is Synapse DW dedicated pools.   You should specify that to not cause confusion - there is no broadcast operator in normal SQL Server.  In general, unless you know a lot about query optimizers and execution engines, it is not recommended that you try to muck with the plan shapes.  In this case, the order of the operations is just fine - you want to take a scalar operation and broadcast it to the other execution nodes for a DW gen2 dedicated plan.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that an inner join is a costly operation when compared with a filter

This is categorically not true. Joins can often be efficient when used correctly.

The reason this query is slow is not because of the join. The join is only presented with a single outer row, whose single value is pushed down to the lower side as an outer reference.

The real reason is because the tables are not indexed properly (or at all). You probably need the following indexes for this to work well

```sql
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX ON TABLE1 (date);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON TABLE2 (date);
```

Table1 needs to have a clustered index because you are querying all columns. You can obviously also use a non-clustered index with `INCLUDE` on all columns but that seems pointless. If you narrow down the columns you are querying then you may be able to get away with an NCI and `INCLUDE`.

Table2 does not need a clustered index for this query as you are only querying the one column. But it may make sense to make this a clustered index anyway.

Primary keys are by default a clustered index, so you may need to rebuild it.